# How to use Word VBA to turn text between <eq></eq> tags into equations?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using Word to format math exams. By default, all the questions I receive have equations written in latex and delimited by the <eq> and </eq> tags. To perform the appropriate formatting, I need to locate each of these tags, select the text within them, and insert an equation. As this is a repetitive task, I know it can be automated using macros, but I don't know anything about VBA. How can I create a macro that goes through the entire document, finds these tags, inserts the equations, and removes the tags?

I don't know if it helps, but the command `Selection.OMaths.Add Range:=Selection.Range` inserts an equation for the selected text.

Example of text:

Find the maximum value of the expression <eq> -2x^2+3x+5 </eq>.

There is no need to to complete the formatation of the expression. I just need to select and insert the equation (alt+=).

Comment: Please share sample data from your doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertEquation()
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim wdRng As Range
    Dim SearchTxt As String
    Const START_TAG = "\<eq\>"
    Const END_TAG = "\</eq\>"
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set wdRng = objDoc.Content
    ' Search with wildcards
    SearchTxt = START_TAG & "*" & END_TAG
    With wdRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = SearchTxt
    End With
    Do While wdRng.Find.Execute
        ' Locate the equation range
        wdRng.MoveStart wdCharacter, Len(START_TAG) - 2
        wdRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 2 - Len(END_TAG)
        ' Convert equation
        wdRng.OMaths.Add Range:=wdRng
        wdRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> Question:  Can it also remove the tags? (from comment)

```vb
Sub ConvertEquation()
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim wdRng As Range
    Dim SearchTxt As String
    Dim EquTxt As String
    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim iOffset As Integer
    Const START_TAG = "\<eq\>"
    Const END_TAG = "\</eq\>"
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set wdRng = objDoc.Content
    ' Search with wildcards
    SearchTxt = START_TAG & "*" & END_TAG
    With wdRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = SearchTxt
    End With
    iStart = Len(START_TAG) - 1
    Do While wdRng.Find.Execute
        ' Remove tag
        EquTxt = wdRng.Text
        iOffset = Len(EquTxt) - Len(START_TAG) - Len(END_TAG) + 4
        EquTxt = VBA.Mid(EquTxt, iStart, iOffset)
        wdRng.Text = EquTxt
        ' Convert equation
        wdRng.OMaths.Add Range:=wdRng
        wdRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Both start and end tags?

Comment: Yes. They are used only to delimit the equation.

Comment: I have updated the code.